# Failed to build EGG files for matplotlib with error of freetype and libpng

Tags: python, matplotlib, libpng, freetype, egg

I'm trying to build EGG files for matplotlib on Windows 7
==> Get "matplotlib-2.1.0rc1.tar.gz" from "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/"
==> Unzip and enter the root folder "matplotlib-2.1.0rc1" by CMD window
==> Run command "python setup.py bdist_egg"

But there are some errors, it is failed to create EGG files for matplotlib
Error messages:
*...

...

freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (freetype2\ft2build.h) could not be found.  You may need to install the development package.]

...

...

png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be found.  You may need to install the development package.]

...

...

The following required packages can not be built: freetype, png

Please check http: //gnuwin32.sourc eforge.net/packages/freetype.htm for instructions to install freetype

Please check http: //gnuwin32 .sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm for instructions to install png*


I've tried many ways (with the tips of error messages, or some other sharing on internet) to install freetpye and libpng, but it's still failed

It seems the "setup.py" of matplotlib cannot recognize the path of freetype and libpng for "ft2build.h" and "png.h"


How should I install freetype and libpng to make matplotlib correctly built?
Is there any other settings wrong in my EGG building steps?
Thanks!

Comment: If you can't solve the issue (I work on linux and hence can't really help), I would consider installing anaconda, which is a bundle of the scientific python stack (including matplotlib and its dependencies). You can get the complete bundle pre-built for windows on their [website](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i give up to build EGG for matplotlib finally...

It seems complicate to build EGG for matplotlib, it requires to include some C header files and libraries
And after the EGG files are finally generated, there are many errors when i try to import them...